# How to write Java code using ther Jubula client API

Tags: api, client, jubula

I am new to the testing environment and have been searching for tutorials on Jubula client API.

Fortunately I have managed to find one, but still I am unable to launch my project. Till now I have installed the JUnit plugin in Jubula and configured the AUT on the standalone. Am I supposed to straight away make the JUnit unit test class or something else has to be done?

Comment: What is *"AUT"*?

Answer (score 0):

There is an FAQ on the Jubula Testing Portal about this:

http://testing.bredex.de/faqs/jubula-api-setup.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the AUT first and map the objects from the app accordingly for usage and launch the test application.

Assign the variables or objects from the [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) or HTML and perform the required testing according to need.

For example:

```
public static final ComponentIdentifier btnFileExit = MakeR.createCI(Object from Jubula); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

Now, perform the required actions on the application and webpage, respectively.